# Refresh table for every 5 seconds for a specific URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Basically i have a dynamic HTML table

`<table id="example"></table>`.

The contents inside the table changes based on the URL. My default
URL will be

```
index.php?action=add
```

For this i have written a function to refresh my table for every 5 seconds, which works fine

```
var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
   $('#example').load('index.php?action=add #example').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

Then i'l change my URL to

`index.php?action=add&subdo=loc`.

This will change the contents inside my HTML table.

So how do i refresh the new contents for every 5 seconds in my HTML table for `index.php?action=add&subdo=loc`

EDIT : I will have to change to multiple URL's for different contents in my TABLE for different URL's. NOT one

```
index.php?action=add&subdo=loc1
index.php?action=add&subdo=loc2
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"Then i'l change my URL to"_? What purpose are you changing it for and at what point?

Comment: you can use setInterval or press F5 for each 5 seconds in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use window.location.search

**try this:** UPDATE

```
var autoLoad = setInterval(
function ()
{
   var url = window.location.search;
   $('#example').load('index.php' + url + ' #example').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make second function

```
var autoLoad2 = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#example').load('index.php?action=add&subdo=loc #example').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

this might solve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right when you change the url in the browser the script remain the same...

did you try using the window.location like:

```
$('#example').load(window.location.href).fadeIn("slow");
```

this way the interval will re-call the current url whatever it is.

Let me know...

Comment: `window.location.pathname` would be better suited for this use case, avoiding all sorts of issues to do with loading a full domain rather than a relative path.

Comment: even better would be to change the table content with an Ajax request.... and avoiding using the url.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var url = '',
  autoLoad = setInterval(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('subdo') != -1) {
      url = 'index.php?action=add&subdo=loc';
    } else {
      url = 'index.php?action=add';
    }
    $('#example').load(url + ' #example').fadeIn("slow");
  }, 5000);
```